# Use step down transformer as step up transformers

Tags: transformer

I have a 3 MVA (11000/415 V) step down transformer. Can I use reverse voltage connection, i.e. 3 MVA (415/11000 V)? If it's possible, what should be the neutral terminal connection? If it's not possible, what should be the main consideration for designing step up transformers?

Comment: Talking about 2-phase transformers: Of course you can connect. Either terminal can be N or L *(Just like isolation -1:1- transformers)*. I've no idea about 3-phase transformers but I think the same thing applies for them as well.

Comment: Generally no, because the turns ratio is sometimes manipulated to get the correct step-down ratio under load and this means that in reverse, the output voltage will fall short of expectations.

Comment: You'd better do nothing with 3MVA 11kV transformer if you have to ask it on this forum.

Comment: Obviously a homework...

Answer (score 5):

Yes and no. Yes you can use a transformer in reverse. The no part has to do with the transformer's design. Secondary or output windings are low impedance to reduce losses and increase efficiency. This is a problem when wiring it in reverse as the low impedance will cause a large inrush current when powering up the transformer or transient loads spike the current (e.g. starting a motor.)

A massive transformer such as yours will likely have very low output impedance and would be difficult to even switch on let alone carry a load. You would need a transformer designed to step up 415V to 11kV.

It's an odd application. I have never heard of someone reversing a large 3MVA 11kv distribution transformer. Is this related to a solar grid tie application?

Comment: Thank You Very much for response my question. And from your answer I dont want to use the same transformer for reversing. Now if I want to design a new step up 3 MVA (0.415 /11 KV) transformer then What should I do to control Inrush Current ? If I use higher impedance in design (like 7.0%) is it work?